# Short Prove or Disprove: $R_1 \cap R_2$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Suppose $R_1, R_2$ are both equivalence relations defined on nonempty set $A$. Prove or disprove: $R_1 \cap R_2$ is an equivalence relation.

What method (if any) would you take to prove this in as few sentences as possible?

Comment: Do you have a way to prove it with a large number of sentences?  If so, please tell us.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what $R_1 \bigcap R_2$ would mean.  Suppose I take $R_1$ on the integers as congruence mod 5; and $R_2$ as congruence mod 6.  What would their intersection be?

Comment: @BettyMock Congruence mod 30.

Comment: @BettyMock A (binary) relation is usually formalized as a set of ordered pairs:  $x \mathbin{R} y$ means $(x,y) \in R$.  In this case we literally take the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: @TrevorWilson No, sorry.

Comment: @Did: I believe Betty Mock wanted Necron to answer her question.

Comment: The method is sometimes called "following your nose".

Comment: @BettyMock, if $R_1, R_2$ are defined on $\mathbb{Z}$. Then for distinct $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a\ R_1\ b \Leftrightarrow a \equiv b (\mod{5})$, and for all distinct $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$,  $a\ R_2\ b \Leftrightarrow a \equiv b (\mod{6})$. Considering both cases $5 \mid (a-b)$ and $6 \mid (a-b)$. This is only possible (without proof) if $5\cdot 6 \mid (a - b)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @BettyMock: See my answer for a way to interpret $R_1\cap R_2$ that may be more compatible with what you're used to.

Comment: @bof Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R=R_1\cap R_2.$ You must show the following:

- For any $a\in A,$ $\langle a,a\rangle\in R.$ ($R$ is *reflexive* on $A$.)
- For any $a,b\in A$, if $\langle a,b\rangle \in R,$ then $\langle b,a\rangle\in R.$ ($R$ is *symmetric* on $A$.)
- For any $a,b,c\in A$, if $\langle a,b\rangle,\langle b,c\rangle\in R,$ then $\langle a,c\rangle\in R$. ($R$ is *transitive* on $A$.)

Each step can be proved very directly and straightforwardly, since $R_1,R_2$ are equivalence relations on $A$. Let me prove symmetry to give you a taste of it.

> Suppose that $a,b\in A$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R.$ Then $\langle a,b\rangle\in R_1,$ so since $R_1$ is symmetric on $A$, then $\langle b,a\rangle\in R_1.$ Likewise, $\langle b,a\rangle\in R_2,$ so $\langle b,a\rangle\in R_1\cap R_2=R.$

---

Alternately, if you're not used to thinking of binary relations as sets of ordered pairs, we can proceed as follows.

We still let $R=R_1\cap R_2.$ By this, we mean that $a\:R\:b$ if and only if $a\:R_1\:b$ and $a\:R_2\:b.$ Then we need to show the following:

- For any $a\in A,$ $a\:R\:a.$
- For any $a,b\in A$, if $a\:R\:b,$ then $b\: R\: a.$
- For any $a,b,c\in A$, if $a\: R\: b$ and $b\:R\:c,$ then $a\:R\:c$.

Each step is again straightforward, and very similar to the approach that would be taken above. Once again, I'll prove symmetry.

> Suppose that $a,b\in A$ such that $a\:R\:b.$ Then $a\:R_1\:b,$ so since $R_1$ is symmetric, then $b\:R_1\:a.$ Likewise, $b\:R_2\:a,$ so $b\:R\:a$ by definition of $R=R_1\cap R_2.$

Comment: Thinking of binary relations as sets of ordered pairs is how I intuitively think of relations.